# Projecting $\mathbb R^3$ onto $\mathbb RP^2$

Tags: algebraic-geometry, projective-geometry, projective-space

I am reading *[Introduction to Algebraic Geometry](http://five-dimensions.org/Textbooks/)* by Justin R. Smith, and Exercise 2 of section 1.6 (p.33) states the following:

> In computer graphics, after a scene in $\mathbb R P^3$ has been constructed, it is
> viewed — i.e., there is a “camera” that photographs the scene with proper perspective.
> Suppose this camera lies at the origin and is pointed in the positive $z$
> direction. Describe the mapping that shows how the scene looks.
> How do we handle the situation where the camera is not at the origin and
> pointed in the $z$-direction?

The answer for the first part (camera at origin) says it is given by (from $\mathbb R^3\subset\def\R{\mathbb R}\R P^3$ to $\R P^2$)

$$\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\\1\end{bmatrix}\mapsto\begin{bmatrix}x\\y\\z\end{bmatrix}$$

I'm very confused by where this comes from, especially because this answer seems totally independent of the fact that the camera is facing $z$-axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, I realize that the point is we are making the plane $z=0$ become points at infinity, and this is achieved by making $z$ (implicitly) the last coordinate in $\mathbb R P^2$.